# animate() and fadeIn() not working as desired

Tags: jquery, css, web, jquery-animate, fadein

I want the third1 div to move inside the third div as it fades in, however, as its position is absolute it is getting positioned properly. Please suggest a solution for this problem. I also want the simultaneous fadeIn and animate effect but the code is not working as desired. Please help!

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="animation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="req.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="one"><button class="b">Click Me!</button></div>
 <div class="two"></div>
 <div class="three">
    <div class="three1 anim" style="position:absolute;"></div>
        <div class="three2 anim"></div>
        <div class="three3 anim"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Also the jquery and css codes are as below:

```
one{
    height: 100%;
width: 400px;
background: rgb(241, 196, 15);
float:left;
}
.two{
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
background: rgb(230, 126, 34);
float:left;
}
.three{
height: 100%;
width: 400px;
background: rgb(231, 76, 60);
float:left;
}
.three1{
height: 100px;
width: 350px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top:15px;
background: rgb(26, 188, 156);
float:left;
postion:absolute;
display:none;
}
.three2{
height: 100px;
width: 350px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top:15px;
background: rgb(46, 204, 113);
float:left;
postion:absolute;
display:none;
}
.three3{
height: 100px;
width: 350px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-top:15px;
background: rgb(52, 152, 219);
float:left;
postion:absolute;
display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.b').click(function(){
        $('.anim').fadeIn(2000);
    $('.anim').animate({left:'100px'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fadeIn and animate don't run at the same time, they queue. I wouldn't do it like this if I were writing from scratch but the easiest way to adjust your code would be to:

- get rid of the display:none in the css
- swap it for an opacity:0
- then adjust your jQuery to read as below

jQuery:

```
$('.anim').animate({left:'100px', opacity: '1'},2000);
```

Here is a jsFiddle with your code that I have amended

http://jsfiddle.net/Wrx2k/

Also, just a little pointer, your position: absolute in the CSS styles has a typo. Also, try to avoid using both stylesheets and inline CSS wherever possible for manageable styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by,

```
$('.anim').animate({'opacity':1,'left':'100px'},2000);
```

Since you are using animations on same element, the second one would be queued, so you can't run the both simultaneously.